# A low cost way to change a sequence of values into hexadecimal characters

Tags: c++, boost, hex, c++14

I have a sequence of values in a payload which is type uint8_t* and it's size is equal to constant size(32).
my target is converting this sequence to hexadecimal characters with small letters.

I wrote this code:

```cpp
size_t constant_size = 12;
const std::String s1(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(payload), constant_size);
std::string final = boost::algorithm::hex(s1);
boost::algorithm::to_lower(final);
```

this code runs well. but it's cost is very high, because i'm using some buffer processing and copies which decrease performance.

is it a better way to convert my data(which it's type is uint8_t*) to hex characters with small letters?

Comment: boost::algorithm::hex_lower can replace your last two lines and improves performance.

Comment: @Lorenzo there isn't any function in boost::algorithm named hex_lower.

Comment: Maybe depends on which boost version you have. In 1.70.0 there is one: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/header/boost/algorithm/hex_hpp.html

Comment: @Lorenzo yes. you are right. thank you.